# Get value from other table laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get value from user table where role_id=2

```
public function index(){
         return view('admin.articles.index',[
        'articles' => Article::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10),
        'articles_suggest' => Article::with('user')->where('user.role_id',2)->paginate(10),
    ]);

}

 Unknown column 'user.role_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `articles` where `user`.`role_id
```

user model

```
public function articles(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
    }
```

article model

```
 public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'author_id');
  }
```

Comment: You are not using in correct way the syntax is `Article::with(['user' => function($query){ $query->where('role_id',2)}])`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would take a look at the @deepak comment. Here is a link about [Eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). Rewrite the index function for something like this:

```
$articles = Article::with(['user' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('role_id', '=', 2);
}])->paginate(10);
```

And then, I guess you could do this in your view:

```
// Looping through articles
@foreach($articles as $article)
    // Check if there is a user associated with the article
    @if( $article->user )
        // Access the user column/attribute
        {{ $article->user->theusercolumn }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: I need to have the correct pagination, because if I check through the IF then the pagination will remain the same as the whole array, only a couple of pages will be filled and all the rest are empty

Comment: I have articles and these users have a different role_id, but it displays everything together

Comment: Any screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

Try callback

```php
'articles_suggest' => Article::with(['user'=>function($q){
    $q->where('role_id',2);
}])->paginate(10),
```

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `articles` where (`user` = (select * where `role_id` = 2)))

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from articles where (user = (select * where role_id = 2)))

Comment: it's return me ALL . as if WHERE this is not

Comment: it will return all user which will having role_id=2 in user table

Comment: I have articles and these users have a different role_id, but it displays everything together

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210805/discussion-between-kamlesh-paul-and-kaiserr).